# How to tail all the log files inside a folder and subfolders?

Tags: unix, logging, command-line, tail

In Linux, using the command `tailf`, how can I tail several log files that are inside a folder and in the subfolders?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

To log all the files inside a folder, you can go to the folder and write

```
tail -f *.log
```

To add the subfolders to the tailf command, use

```
tail -f **/*.log
```

Of course, the regular expression can be improved to match only specific file names.

Comment: To to tail folder+ sub folders `tail -f ../logs/**/*log* ../logs/*log*`

Comment: Is there a way to tail all files and all new files (doesn't exist yet)?

Comment: `multitail -Q 5 '/path/to/logs/*'` - where 5 is number of seconds to check for new files. Install it using `apt-get install multitail` or `yum` or whatever.

Comment: `tailf **/*.log` Works with only one level of sub-folders

Comment: thank you @luchaninov, `multitail` was exactly what I was looking for.  If I had 5 files, for instance, I wanted to see all 5 of them on the terminal at once and only the last few lines of each as the data changed.

Answer (score 32):

This will recursively find all *.log files in current directory and its subfolders and tail them.

`find . -type f \( -name "*.log" \) -exec tail -f "$file" {} +`

Or shortly with xargs:

`find . -name "*.log" | xargs tail -f`

Answer (score 18):

If all log files doesn't have same extension. You can use following command.

```
tail -f **/*
```

Comment: @farid-movsumov Could you please explain the meaning of **/*?

Answer (score 3):

To formalize the comment by luchaninov into an answer, `multitail` is useful if the set of filenames changes. In contrast, `tail` doesn't seem to be able to find new files that were created after it was started.

Installation:

```
sudo apt install multitail
```

Manual:

```
man multitail
```

Usage:

```
multitail -Q 4 '/path/to/logs/*.log'
```

The above command should check the quoted pattern every specified number of seconds for new files. The pattern must be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

This way find files recursively, print lines starting on line 5 in the each file and save on concat.txt

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.dat" \) -exec tail -n+5 -q "$file" {} + |tee concat.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

One can try using & for that purpose in between the logs statements like

```
tail -f /app/temp/logs/C1/a.log & tail -f /app/temp/logs/C2/b.log
```