# Tail log files within all subfolders

Tags: linux, shell, tail

I'm trying to get a simple script going which looks at all .log files and greps for a particular string and depending on its value sends an email.

```
tail -f **/*.log | while read LOGLINE

do 
        [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"complete!"* ]] && pkill -P $$ tail | 
                echo "LOG" | mutt -s "Test Passed!" abc@xyz.com

        [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"FAILURE"* ]] && pkill -P $$ tail | 
                echo "LOG" | mutt -s "Test Failed!" abc@xyz.com

done
```

However this gives me the following results:

```
tail: cannot open `**/*.log' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: no files remaining
```

If I provide the exact path, the script works fine. 
How can I make this work for all the .log files in the parent and all sub-folders?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `**`?

Comment: @e0k Trying to follow the example given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321336/how-to-tail-all-the-log-files-inside-a-folder-and-subfolders where they suggested  "**/*.log"

Comment: OK, `**/` is from the [globstar](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) option and matches only directories and subdirectories.  Is the `globstar` option enabled in the shell?  Are the `.log` files in the current directory or subdirectories?

Answer (score 1):

In my bash shell, the `globstar` option is off by default.  You can enable it with

```
    shopt -s globstar
```

This should allow expansion of `**/*.log` into all subdirectories.  See also [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option).  See if this finds your .log files.

Note: This feature was introduced in bash 4.0.  If you're using an older version, this would explain why the code doesn't work (your shell doesn't have that feature).

An alternative is to use `find`.  Replace the `**/*.log` with `$(find . -name '*.log')` so the line reads

```
    tail -f $(find . -name '*.log') | while read LOGLINE
```

In case you don't have permissions of some subdirectories, for example, it could give error messages too which go to *stderr* (file 2).  You can remove them with a redirection

```
    $(find . -name '*.log' 2>/dev/null)
```

Comment: Nope, I get an invalid option name                                                       $shopt -s globstar
bash: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name
(GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu))

Comment: What happens if you type only `shopt` at a bash prompt?  It should list every shell option and if it's on or off.  Look for `globstar`.

Comment: Oh I see the problem now, you're using an old version of bash.  This `globstar` option was introduced in 4.0 (see the link on my answer).  So you can't use that `**/*.log` syntax as it was intended.

Comment: BTW, I _strongly_ recommend upgrading your bash due to the [shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29) bug, which is a security issue.

Comment: Yes, it was added in 4.0 as you mentioned. Alas I dont have rights to upgrade it - its tightly controlled by IT so I'll put in a request. Is there another way around this? Using find to recursively look at all .log files and use those to look for the pattern? Appreciate your suggestions.